# Function that automatically converts the date format for every date column in a query result?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Date information in my database is formatted in unixtime to the millisecond. Currently, in order to convert a result set into MST I use this function string:

```
 date_format(convert_tz(from_unixtime(table.column/1000),'utc','us/mountain')'%m/%d/%Y')
```

I have a routine which I can apply to individual columns in my query that looks like this:

```
create function datefmt(convert_tz(TEDATE bigint, TEFMT text),'gmt','us/mountain')
   returns varchar(50);
```

This works fine when I'm specifically calling date columns, but I can't apply it to all date columns in a select * statement. This can make running general queries quite tedious, especially with joins (as most of the tables I use have between 3-6 date columns)!

I am trying to figure out how to create something that will recognize every date column in the result set and then apply the date formatting to all rows in the applicable columns. I've considered using triggers, user defined functions, and routines. But I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly how I can accomplish this feat, or if it can even be accomplished.

An example table would be "Task" with these date columns: rowAddedDate (bigint not null), rowUpdatedDate (bigint not null), createdDate (bigint not null), orderedDate (bigint not null), serviceEndDate (int null), serviceStartDate (int null), expectedServiceDate (int null).

I use a clone, and the database software is MariaDB v 10.2.12.

Any help regarding this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In sql server would use dynamic sql for this - go row by row through the sys table grabbing each field in your table that's a date, apply your transformation, and then write that data to a temp table and select from there - adjust as needed for mysql

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have a direction you could point me to in creating this kind of tool? Could a trigger work for when i refresh/recreate my clone?

The database I draw from has over 250 tables, but in the short term I could try applying this to the top ten I personally use.

Comment: Not sure how to do it in MySQL but sql server allows you to create a loop and pass each value from your sys tables one by one into your query - ill demonstrate below:

Answer (score 0):

Looping with dynamic sql demonstration in sql server:

```
create table #temp (rowid int identity, test varchar(max))
insert #temp
values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

declare @iterator int = 1
declare @maxrows int = (select max(rowid) from #temp)
while @iterator<=@maxrows
begin
exec('select test from #temp where rowid='+@iterator+'')
set @iterator=@Iterator+1
end
```

Comment: Now imagine doing this while selecting every datetime field from the table you are working with using sys table 'sys_columns' and the objectid of your table...

Comment: Thanks for the example! I'll try experimenting with temporary tables when I get a minute and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the columns should have been `TIMESTAMP(3)`, not `DATETIME(3)` or some hack with `BIGINT`.  (Looks like you have the `BIGINT`.)

That way, you could `SET` the timezone once, and all times would be automatically converted.